# huludesktop gives a blank gray window

Tags: flash, hulu

When I start huludesktop, it creates a blank, gray window. It doesn't print any warnings or errors... but it also doesn't do anything else, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The huludesktop application can do this when it is looking in the wrong place for the flash plugin. Check `~/.huludesktop` for a `flash` section. For example, in my corrected file, I have these two lines:

```
[flash]
flash_location = /usr/lib64/flash-plugin/libflashplayer.so
```

You can find the right location to add via the command `locate libflashplayer.so` (perhaps running `updatedb` first if you have only recently installed flash).